# How to delete a pointer for an object?

Tags: c++, pointers, free

I've searched for this but didn't find a similar topic.

If I have an object class, for example `class Object { ... };` , and I have this pointer for it: `Object* p = new Object();`

I was wondering what is the correct way to delete this pointer, is it this:

`delete (Object*) p;`

Or this:

`delete[] p;`

I can't tell which one is the correct, I would be happy if someone could tell me what's right.
Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

If you are just allocate a single object using the `new` operator you should use `delete` to free that some object. If you are using the `new[]` operator (which is the array form) though to allocate multiple objects at once you should use `delete[]` to delete those accordingly.

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/

Comment: Thank you, same thing I asked him, what if I'm doing Object** p, an array of pointers of the type Object, do I pass on them one by one with loop and delete them or there is a different way ?

Answer (score 0):

> is it this:
>
> ```
> delete (Object*) p;
> ```

It is not. There is no need to cast an object of type `Object*` to the type `Object*`. That is redundant. Furthermore, C-style cast should be avoided.

> Or this:
>
> ```
> delete[] p;
> ```

It is not. `delete[]` must be used only with pointers returned from a `new[]` expression. You didn't use `new[]`, so you may not use `delete[]`. You used `new`, so you must use `delete`.

The correct way is `delete p;`. However, you probably shouldn't have done `Object* p = new Object();` in the first place. Instead use `auto p = std::make_unique<Object>();`. This way the allocation is deleted automatically and it will be much harder to write bugs. Also consider whether you need dynamic allocation in the first place. It should be avoided when it is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you, though what if I'm doing this: Object** p, which means array of pointers to the type Object? do I still pass with a loop on each one and delete it the way you showed me ?

Comment: @ConanCoder `Object** p` is not an array of pointers. It is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Okay but I can look at it as if it's an array correct ? and still how do I free that ?

Comment: @ConanCoder It doesn't matter how you look at it. What matters is how you have allocated. If you allocate with `new`, then use `delete`. If you have allocated with `new[]`, then use `delete[]`.

Comment: Awesome, I think I got it, thanks for the help <3